# The best overloaded method match for 'DataClass.addrechargeplans(string, string, string, int, string, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

> The overload method match for ....has some invalid arguments      In
>   the database we have table name "RechargePlans" and columns names are
>   Circle,Operator,RechargeType,Amount,Talktime,Validity,Description

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      int i = 0;
      i = obj.addrechargeplans(circleddl.SelectedItem.Text, operatorddl.SelectedItem.Value,rechargetype.SelectedItem.Text, amt, taktme.Text, valdty.Text, descpn.Text);
        if (i > 0)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert(' inserted')</script>");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('error')</script>");
        }
     }
```

**Data Class**

```
public int addrechargeplans(string Circle, string Operator, string RechargeType, int     Amount, string Talktime, string Validity, string Description)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_rechargeplans";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@circle", Circle);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@operator", Operator);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rechargetype", RechargeType);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", Amount);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@talktime", Talktime);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@validity", Validity);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", Description);
        int i;
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return i;
    }
```

Comment: what is the type of `amt` ?

Comment: The error message should tell you the types it tries to use and what the method is declared to use, please look at the full compiler error to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: This should be a straight forward error and can be resolved pretty easy, could you check what amt is?

Answer (score 5):

According to error message you have at least one invalid argument. We don't know what is the type of `amt` variable.It should be an `integer` according to your method definition.

Comment: I guess it is `amt` which is not integer.

Comment: `operatorddl.SelectedItem.Value` is a string but +1 for your second part of the answer.

Comment: @Habib yeah you was right I checked Value propert it is string

Comment: @Tajkumar apparently it isn't.Please check it again